# Search text in list of files

Tags: linux, bash, search, find, grep

I'm trying to execute double search within files and return file names.

I'm using

```
find ./ -iname '*txt' | xargs grep "searchtext" -sl
```

to find file names with 'searchtext' in them.

Command is returning a list of files.

How can I find "othersearchtext" in those already found files and show them in the same fashion?

Comment: It's fine if the answer is below. Please don't add an answer to your *question*. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feed the result to another `grep` by using backticks or equivalent $().

If you want to keep the intermediate list, use `tee`

```
grep -l oranges $(find . -name "*txt" | xargs grep -l apples | tee apples.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks!
grep -l "othersearchtext" $(find . -iname '*txt' | xargs grep "searchtext" -sl)

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `xargs grep …`:

```
find . -iname '*txt' | \
    xargs grep -l "searchtext" | \
    xargs grep -l "othersearchtext" | \
    xargs grep -l "yetanothersearchtext"
```

Answer (score 0):

This bash will search multiple strings in given folder recursively and return filenames

Usage:

```
findfiles /var/www/ php searchText1 searchText2 searchText3 searchText4
```

bash: findfiles

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR=$1
EXT=$2

CMD="find $DIR -iname '*.$EXT' | xargs grep -l '$3' | xargs grep -l '$4' | xargs grep -l '$5' | xargs grep -l '$6' | xargs grep -l '$7' | xargs grep -l '$8' | xargs grep -l '$9'"

eval $CMD
```